# What is the purpose of shared folder in active directory?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-xp, network-share

I recently noticed `Shared Folder` under `New` in `Active Directory Users and Computers`.  What is the purpose of creating a shared folder in active directory?  Where would it appear to a user?

Server: Windows 2003; Client: Windows XP

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't share the folder, it simply publishes it in active directory (to make it searchable).  You have to have shared the folder first.  More details at the following KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234582

Comment: Under `My Network Places/Entire Network` I have `Microsoft Terminal Services`, `Microsoft Windows Network`, and `Web Client Network`.  I do NOT have the promised `Entire Contents`